# there is two hour time difference between events recived at IOT hub and time at which event delivered to datapipeline topology

Tags: apache, apache-storm, iot, azure-eventhub

I am working on storm  topology . When I checked the storm log I can see that there is two hour time difference between time at which events are received at IOT hub and the time on which events delivered to data pipeline my topology.

Can anyone have any idea what might be the probable cause of this time lag.

Comment: Are you taking in account any timezones etc?

Comment: Devices , IOT hub and , topology server are in same timezone

Comment: Can you show the log where you found the two-hour time difference?